# RequiredFieldValidator error_message appears after form is submitted

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I submit form and the clear all the fields from code behind, and when page is re-rendered RequiredFieldValidator error message appears. I am submitting form and not using button's click event. 
How can i avoid seeing validator message after form is posted back?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Web Forms?

Comment: Is the submit button a server control or html <input type='submit' ... /> ??

Comment: Post your code it will help you find a solution quicker.

Comment: `//Textbox and validator
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="591px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                        ErrorMessage="* missing" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="SaveData"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

//Asp server control
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="SaveData"/>`

Comment: I have lot of code in code behind but what i am doing is like following.

`       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
            
            }
            else
            {
                SaveRecordToDB();

                TextBox1.text = string.Empty();
            }

        }`

Comment: Client want to remain on the same page and display success message. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a Response.Redirect to a 'saved successfully' page rather than posting back to itself unless you need to stay on that page. But I will add a solution below if you want to remain on this page......

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            SaveRecordToDB();
            Response.Redirect("/");
        }
    }
```

Assuming the submit page is the Default.aspx otherwise just redirect back to your own form page.

Comment: Check out this page, it has a different way of using the button but the validation works on that example correctly: http://www.vkinfotek.com/validationcontrols.html