# RequiredFieldValidator error messages displayed after successful Postback and form reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

(Using ASP.NET Web Forms. Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319, ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274)

I have an asp:TextBox field with a RequiredFieldValidator for that text field:

```
<asp:TextBox 
    runat="server" 
    ID="MyTextBox" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    runat="server"
    ID="RequiredUserName"
    ControlToValidate="MyTextBox" 
    ErrorMessage="MyTextBox is required"
    Display="None" />
```

When the user submits the form on the page, I validate it and then clear the form so that they user can use the form again. The code behind in `Page_Load` looks like:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        SaveFormSubmissionToDatabase();
        MyTextBox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

So, I validate everything, it Page.IsValid is true, I save the users form data and then try to clear the form for the user to fill in again. But since the form is cleared, the RequiredFieldValid shows its error message, even though I have already run `Page.Validate()` and have not run it again.

Why is this and what can I do to avoid this error message from being displayed after I clear my form? More generally, why is this RequiredFieldValidator being run again?

I should note that the error message is actually being displayed in an `asp:ValidationSummary` control.

(I thought that maybe client side validation was triggering the error messages being displayed, so I set `EnableClientScript="false"` in the RequiredFieldValidator, but that didn't change anything)

---

I have researched this issue for a bit and have found other people with the same issue, but no solution. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036475/requiredfieldvalidator-error-message-appears-after-form-is-submitted), for example. The proposed solution there is to redirect to the same page, which doesn't work form my use case because I need to display some information about the form that was just submitted, including a success message, and that information would be lost if I redirected to the same page.

Comment: Can you delete the error when you clear the form? This is a workaround

Comment: @erikscandola, I could, but I'd like to understand the source of the error and see if there is another solution before resorting to something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you get the message is because of the call to Page.Validate() which is exactly what is for as the name indicates. And because with every postback the validate is called.

Typically you would not put that code in the Page_Load, but in the submit button's onClick.

i.e.:

```
    protected void SubmitButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            SaveFormSubmissionToDatabase();
            MyTextBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Update: Let me refine the reason. In the original post the `MyTextBox.Text = ""` is not the last thing that happens. The controls on the page will also fire their events and validations, and this happens after the Page_Load event.

For full life-cycle reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#general_page_lifecycle_stages

Comment: Thanks for the help Frank, but I don't quite see how that could be the issue. My call to `Page.Validate()` leaves `Page.IsValid` as true, so there shouldn't be any error messages. Then I clear my form so the user can enter it again, and the required field validators fail. Why would putting it in a different part of the code behind change how the same calls behave?

Comment: That is because the `Page_Load` is early in the life-cycle of the page. All controls, including the validators, will do their stuff after Page_Load and find the page not valid anymore.
You could short-circuit this by setting `RequiredUserName.Enabled = false` and then in the OnLoadComplete() re-enable it.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try putting it in the on-click for the button and see if it gets me anywhere. If it does, I'll certainly mark your answer! Thanks.

Comment: Frank, this did indeed solve my issue, and I very much appreciate you adding the information on the life cycle explaining how the validation is triggered after I set the text to empty.